# Mapping graph to another graph's sub-graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

How to solve the induced sub-graph isomorphism problem?

Comment: Are your graphs of a particular type, e.g. planar?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the updated question, yes, it can be solved with a SAT solver.  The problem is NP-complete, so it is in NP, so therefore it can be reduced to SAT, i.e., expressed in CNF-SAT (see [What is the definition of P, NP, NP-complete and NP-hard?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9556/755)).  Then you can use an off-the-shelf SAT solver to solve here.

For general techniques, take a look at [Converting (math) problems to SAT instances](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12087/755) and [NP to SAT. How does it works?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/50469/755).

Here are some questions that might also be useful:

- [Encoding 1-out-of-n constraint for SAT solvers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13188/755)
- [Reduce Vertex cover to SAT](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22426/755)
- [Reduce the following problem to SAT](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/6521/755)

Answer (score 4):

This is the [induced subgraph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph_isomorphism_problem), which was one of the problems proven **NP**-complete in Cook's original paper on **NP**-completeness.  For a quick way to see that it's **NP**-complete, you can let $G$ be a complete graph on $k$ vertices to solve CLIQUE on $G'$. Unless you can restrict the form of $G$ and/or $G'$, you're probably out of luck in your quest for a good algorithm.

The problem seems to be easier if you insist that $G$ and $G'$ have the same number of vertices. In this case, you have the [graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem). This is generally thought not to be **NP**-complete and, in December 2015, [Babai announced an subexponential-time algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03547), which runs in time $\exp\exp(\tilde{O}(\sqrt{\log n}))$, where $\tilde{O}$ denotes hidden factors of $O(\log\log n)$.
This is faster than $O(\mathrm{e}^{n^\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$. (The algorithm was originally announced as having quasipolynomial running time but an error in the analysis [came to light](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/update.html) in January 2017.)

Comment: [Babai retracted the claim of quasipolynomial runtime](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/update.html). Apparently there was an error in the analysis.

Comment: @Raphael Aww, crap. That's a shame.

Comment: Yup. But a useful reminder that we should be more careful when posting about unknowns on websites... \*sigh\* Had to post that comment a couple of times. ;D